# Get records to a <select> in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, eloquent

I have to in my application need to bring the records that are foreign keys in a select.
In the select I need it to show the name of a plate of food(char), that's all.

I have the tables of :
**plato**
y
**platoIngrediente** (where the foreign keys are), like this:

plato migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePlatosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('platos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->char('nombre',50);
            $table->double('valor', 8, 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('platos');
    }
}
```

platoIngrediente migration:

```
  <?php

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreatePlatoIngredienteTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
        Schema::create('platoIngrediente', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('plato_id');
        $table->foreign('plato_id')->references('id')->on('plato');
        $table->unsignedInteger('plato_id');
        $table->foreign('ingrediente_id')->references('id')->on('ingrediente');
        $table->double('cantidad', 8, 2);
        $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
             Schema::dropIfExists('platoIngrediente');

        }
    }
```

platoIngrediente Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PlatoIngrediente extends Model
{
    public $table = "platoIngrediente";

    protected $fillable = ['cantidad'];


    public function platos(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Plato','id_plato');
    }

    public function ingredientes(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Ingrediente','id_ingrediente');
    }

}
```

platoIngredienteController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\PlatoIngrediente;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PlatoIngredienteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $platoingrediente = PlatoIngrediente::all();
    return view('platoingrediente/index', compact('platoIngrediente'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('platoingrediente/create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\PlatoIngrediente  $platoIngrediente
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\PlatoIngrediente  $platoIngrediente
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\PlatoIngrediente  $platoIngrediente
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function formulario(){
        $platos = Platos::with('platos','ingredientes')->get();
        return view('/platoingrediente/index', compact('$platos'));

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\PlatoIngrediente  $platoIngrediente
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and the view:

```
<div class="up sombra card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Creacion del plato
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="up">
  @if(session()->get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      {{ session()->get('success') }}  
    </div><br />
  @endif


  <dd>Primero selecciona un plato: </dd>
  <select class="custom-select">

  <option selected>[ SELECCIONA UN PLATO ]</option>
  <option value="$plato->id">{{ $plato->nombre }}</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>

</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Need more code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the $platos

```
@foreach($platos as $plato)
  <option value=">{{ $plato->nombre }}">{{ $plato->nombre }}</option>
@endofeach
```

Comment: Undefined variable: plato (0)

Comment: From your code, you are sending "Plato Ingredientes" to the view, not Platos. Do you mind the Platos repeating or you only want to list the Unique Platos?

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
    public function index(){
        $platoingrediente = PlatoIngrediente::pluck('nombre', 'id');

        return view('platoingrediente/index', compact('platoingrediente'));
    }
```

In blade file:

```
  <select class="custom-select">
     <option selected>[ SELECCIONA UN PLATO ]</option>

     @forelse($platoingrediente as $key => $val)
         <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $val }}</option>
     @empty
     @endforelse
  </select>
```